# How to add an element inside list of a list in F#

Tags: list, f#

I have a list int int like this:

```
let x = [[2; 3; 4]; [4; 5]; [2; 3]]
```

and an int for example 1. I want to add this int on the first list and return result like this:

```
[[1; 2; 3; 4]; [4; 5]; [2; 3]]
```

What is the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: which particular part are you stuck on? - If you show your work you will get better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let x = [[2; 3; 4]; [4; 5]; [2; 3]]
let addedOne = x |> List.mapi (fun i t -> if i = 0 then 1::t else t)
```

That gives you:

```
val x : int list list = [[2; 3; 4]; [4; 5]; [2; 3]]
val addedOne : int list list = [[1; 2; 3; 4]; [4; 5]; [2; 3]]
```

A more general function:

```
let addToIndex index x l =
  l |> List.mapi (fun i t -> if i = index then x::t else t)
```

As per Johns solution a version that uses Head:

```
let addToHead x =
  function
  |[] -> [[x]]
  |h::t -> (x::h)::t
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know if there is any solution with using Head ? because Head is first element of a list

Comment: Johns solution below uses Head in the pattern patch. You just need to add the [] case to fix the warning.

Comment: Thank you, Actually All my question was about this syntax (x::h)::t, I think I tried it before asking the question, but it gave syntax error in visual studio, now it works :)))

Answer (score 2):

A simple way

```
x |> function |h::t -> (1::h)::t
```

we pattern match to get the first sublist as `h` and then join on to it and provide a result.

Comment: It's correct but has warning: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).